# How can I add variables that are assigned during a loop?

Tags: c++

This might seem like a simple question, I have looked for solutions or just concepts behind this, but cannot find any.

How can I create a loop that asks for as many integers as the user wishes, and once the user types in the value `99` the loop will exit and will display the average of all the numbers inside of the loop?

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  // Variables
  int numInput;
  int numOfIntegers;
  bool canContinue;

  cout << "Enter the amount of integers you would like to enter: ";
  cin >> numOfIntegers;

  int oldNums = new int [numOfIntegers];

  while (canContinue) {
    cout << "Enter a random integer: ";
    cin >> numInput;
    if (numInput != -1) {

    } else {
      canContinue = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `new int[]` returns a `int*` which can't be assigned to `int`. `oldNums` would need to be a pointer. However, please us a `std::vector<int>` instead of managing your memory yourself. It's easier, cleaner and safer using `std::vector`.

Comment: `numInput != -1` should probably be comparing against 99

Comment: `int oldNums = new int [numOfIntegers];` What makes you think this line is syntactically correct? Didn't the compiler tell you that it's wrong? BTW you should use a `std::vector<int>` to represent an _array_.

Comment: You don't need an array here at all.  What two pieces of data do you need to calculate the average of something?  So you see a why how you can get both of those by just taking each number in and doing something with them?

Comment: Add your input values to a container ([std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is a good default choice). And there's No need for manual memory management.

Comment: read a number from the user. If it is not 99, add it to the sum, increment a counter, and loop back to read another number. If it is 99, divide the sum by the counter, print the result, and exit the loop. You may have to watch out for integer division discarding the remainder of the division. No storage of anything other than the sum and the count is required.

Comment: @NathanOliver It's not two numbers, I need the user to enter as many integer numbers and he/she would like and then find the average of all of these numbers.

Comment: @user4581301 - Thank you so much! I can't believe that this did not come to mind. I really appreciate your answer! :)

Comment: Yes.  But you really only need two numbers to do that.  The sum of all the numbers, and how many numbers there are.  Do you see how you could just add the inputs into a running total and then divide that at the end?

Comment: @NathanOliver You are right. I need the sum and the number of numbers that were used. I am going to create a counter inside a loop that tracks every loop and will divide the sum by the counter like user4581301 said. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    int numInput;
    int sum = 0;
    int cnt = 0;

    while (true) {
        cout << "Enter a random integer: ";
        cin >> numInput;

        if (numInput == 99) {
            break;
        }

        sum += numInput;
        cnt++;
    }

    cout << "Average: " << ((double) sum / (double) cnt);

    return 0;
}
```

You don't need to save all the individual values in a array. Adding all values and then divide by the counter it's enough. Casting to `double` avoids losing precision in the average

Comment: It is best not to give concrete answers to questions like this as they are often tests of a programmer's abilities. If your answer is cut-and-pasted, it's your work being evaluated, not theirs.